# Are there any lower bounds on generalization error?

Tags: machine-learning, error

There are multifarious generalization error upper bounds in terms of VC dimension , uniform stability and Rademacher complexity and recent work in terms of mutual information and total variational information. I was wondering if there are established lower bounds on the generalization error ?